# How to print the positions of duplicate largest elements in a matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, printf, dynamic-programming

I am trying to print the position of the largest element of the last column in a matrix. But there arises an issue when a user inputs duplicate elements like this-

```
Matrix A =
|1  2  1|
|2  1  2|
|4  0  3|
|1  1  2|
|2  2  3|
```

instead of inputting like this

```
Matrix B =
|1  2  1|
|2  1  2|
|4  0  3|
|1  1  0|
|2  2  1|
```

Here, 3 is the largest element of the last column in Matrix A.

If I run this code, It will only print the position (2,2)

```
    int index = DP[0][c - 1];
    int indexRow=0;
    for (int row = 1; row < r; row++)
    {
        if (DP[row][c - 1] > index)
        {
            index = DP[row][c - 1];
            indexRow = row;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nIt is in (%d,%d) cell\n\n", indexRow, c-1);
```

But I also wish to print the (4,2) position

or position of duplicate largest elements if something like Matrix A is inserted.

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The naive solution is to just do a second pass over the matrix (and its last column) to find any duplicate values and then print their positions. Have you tried that? Is that enough to satisfy the competition site (this reads very much like a competition site assignment)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, bro. It worked.